# Personalizar o consumo do Json - Web API

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api, controller

Eu tenho a seguinte informação em Json:

```
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "Cditemcontacli": 1.0,
    "Cdcontacli": 1.0,
    "Descricao": "Produto 1"
  },
  {
    "$id": "2",
    "Cditemcontacli": 2.0,
    "Cdcontacli": 2.0,
    "Descricao": "Produto 2"
  },
  {
    "$id": "3",
    "Cditemcontacli": 3.0,
    "Cdcontacli": 2.0,
    "Descricao": "Produto 3"
  },
  {
    "$id": "4",
    "Cditemcontacli": 4.0,
    "Cdcontacli": 3.0,
    "Descricao": "Produto 4"
  }]
```

Controller:

```
//GET: api/Itemcontaclis/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Itemcontacli))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetItemcontacli(decimal id)
        {
            Itemcontacli itemcontacli = await db.Itemcontacli.FindAsync(id);
            if (itemcontacli == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(itemcontacli);
        }
```

Web Api config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{Action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

Quero trazer somente os que tiverem `Cdcontacli:2.0`.
Se observar o `Cdcontacli:2.0` se repete. É possível buscar de alguma forma os dois juntos?
Obrigado.

Comment: Qual a estrutura da classe Itemcontacli  no C#?

Comment: Desculpa a minha ignorância, se refere a isto? 
    public partial class Itemcontacli
    {
        public decimal Cditemcontacli { get; set; }
        public decimal Cdcontacli { get; set;
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

Comment: É exatamente isso, seu método de busca do banco de dados FindAsync que recebe um ID não tem nenhum método que retorna todos os itens? Sem necessariamente precisar de uma ID? 
Por que como está ai não da para ajudar você, precisamos de mais informações. Qual banco de dados está usando? De onde vem esse método FindAsync? Pergunto isso porque existem N maneiras de resolver isso que você quer fazer, precisamos dessas informações para conseguir te orientar na melhor delas.

Comment: Tem sim o método que retorna todos os itens, não publiquei porque achei que não seria necessário. Mas acho que estou conseguindo resolver de outra forma. Mesmo assim vou editar a pergunta e publicar o método. Obrigado @ErickGallani.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido com o seguinte código implementado no controller:

```
// GET: api/Itemcontaclis/cdContaCli
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetPelaConta(decimal idContaCli)
        {
            return Ok(await db.Itemcontacli.Where(x => x.Cdcontacli == idContaCli).ToListAsync());
        }
```